# Запятая нужна после "всю неделю" или после "ноября"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Всю неделю с 19 по 23 ноября действует специальный промокод, а с ним специальная цена сеансов.

Comment: Вопрос требует знака препинания. Угадайте какого?

Comment: Я не стал ждать, пока автор появится, и добавил знак вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Можно применить два подхода (в зависимости от контекста и воли автора).

1. Можно считать, что интервал дат (с 19 по 23 ноября) обозначает, характеризует неделю (мы говорим о неделе с 19 по 23 ноября). Тогда никакие знаки препинания не ставятся:

**Всю неделю с 19 по 23 ноября действует специальный промокод.**

Пример из Нацкорпуса:

> Основным событием недели с 05.07.2004 по 09.07.04 стали, индекс деловой активности в сфере услуг в США и решение Банком Англии оставить основную процентную ставку без изменения на уровне 4, 50%. [Владислав Антонов. Обзор GBPUSD на 12.07.2004 // Forex Magazine, 2004]

2. Можно считать интервал дат всего лишь пояснением к словам "всю неделю" (всю неделю, а именно с 19 по 23 ноября). Тогда требуется обособить это уточнение:

**Всю неделю, с 19 по 23 ноября, действует специальный промокод.**

Пример из Нацкорпуса:

> Как сообщил вчера Банк России, за неделю, с 10 по 17 октября, объем международных резервов снизился на 14, 9 млрд долл. [Мария Селиванова, Полина Смородская,Татьяна Фроловская, Андрей Котов, Роман Кириллов. Не туда пересмотрели (2008.10.24) // http://www.rbcdaily.ru/2008/10/24/focus/387425.shtml, 2008]

Comment: В первом примере ненужная запятая (после "стали").

Comment: @Сибиряк Согласен, запятая после "стали" не нужна, но из песни слова не выкинешь, ззпятая есть в Нацкорпусе. Говорят, лишние запятые могут там появляться как результат машинной обработки текста (какое-то пятно на бумаге может быть воспринято как запятая).